# Form/Class in C# is not getting detected in Intellisense while coding

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I was using visual studio 2010. But shifted the whole project in visual studio 2008 (By add existing item techniqe).

Whole project is running good. But my problem is that when i adds new form to the project (add new windowsform) it is getting added into the soution. But while calling it...it is not getting detected.
Eg. When i tries to call it from button click of other form like

```
rptAllEnquiries obj =new rptAllEnquiries();
obj.show();
```

this rptAllEnquiries doesnt comes in the list which is the form i newly added to the project.

What can be the problem?
Any project or form property is missed by me?

Comment: I've seen this before... I think using `Clean Solution...` from the context-menu, on the top-level solution name in the solution explorer, might fix it?  Otherwise, try closing VS and re-opening the solution.

Comment: Side note: please consider using CamelCase for type names in publicly shared code as recommended by coding guidelines.

Comment: @ Sepster: sir, i have tried both of that but still a problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common reason can be that the old files and the new Windows Forms file might have different namespaces. Check the first line on your `*.cs` files and make sure both have the same custom `namespace`.

Comment: Yeah. Namespace problem was there. Thank You very much.